# Disable Secure Cookies While Debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

In the Web.Config file, I have the following line:

```
 <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

This works great when the site is published, but when debugging, the really annoying thing is that it produces the following unhandled exception:

> The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not
>   present.

In order to overcome this issue, every time I have to comment that Web.Config line while debugging.

I am wondering if there is something similar to RemoteOnly that turns it off in debugging Mode as below, or maybe any other alternative

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Error.cshtml">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/.../HttpError404" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: Use web.config transformations which works just like `RemoteOnly`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `web.config` transform for your production build configuration to set these attributes so the base – debugging – configuration does not include them.

MSDN has an introduction to these tranforms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I added the following line to the Web.Release.Config file:     <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" xdt:Transform="Replace" />